# Setting an array in the HLSL shader

Tags: c++, directx11, hlsl

I have a array of six float4x4's in my shader.

```
cbuffer pseudeocb
{
    float4x4 Mypseudo[6];
};
```

I need to set these in my code.

```
ID3DX11EffectMatrixVariable* Pseudo;
void SetPseudo(CXMMATRIX M) { Pseudo->SetMatrix(reinterpret_cast<const float*>(&M)); }
Pseudeo = mFX->GetVariableByName("Mypseudo")->AsMatrix();
```

This will set one. **How do I set six of them?** Do I need a `SetPseudo` function?

Can I do something like the following:

```
XMMATRIX *p = new XMMATRIX[6];

or

XMMATRIX p[6];
```